# End of line, FileWriter \n

Tags: java, android, append, newline, filewriter

I'm trying to append a newline to an already existing file, but all commands I've tried have resulted in just appending to the first line. I want the output in the file to look like

ROW1

ROW2

```
 private void addToFavToFile(String site){
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        try{
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/test2.txt",true));
            writer.write("ROW1");
            writer.newLine();
            writer.write("ROW2");
            writer.close();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following code and it seems to produce what you are after.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestNewLines {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestNewLines testFiles = new TestNewLines();
    testFiles.addToFavToFile("");
}

private void addToFavToFile(String site){
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try{
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt",true));
        insertEmptyLine(writer);
        writer.write("ROW1: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        insertEmptyLine(writer);
        writer.write("ROW2: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        insertSeperator(writer);
        writer.close();
    } catch(Exception e){

    }
}

private void insertEmptyLine(BufferedWriter writer) throws IOException {
    writer.newLine();
    writer.newLine();
}

private void insertSeperator(BufferedWriter writer) throws IOException {
    writer.newLine();
    writer.write("********************");
}
}
```

To test it I put the line "This is the first line." at the start of my test file. After running it a few times, the output looks like this:

> This is the first line.
>
> ROW1: 1335189657127
>
> ROW2: 1335189657127
>
> ---
>
> ROW1: 1335189658390
>
> ROW2: 1335189658390
>
> ---
>
> ROW1: 1335189665738
>
> ROW2: 1335189665738
>
> ---
>
> ROW1: 1335189679638
>
> ROW2: 1335189679638
>
> ---

As you can see from the timestamps, I am appending new lines to the end of the file each time.

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code,

```
private void addToFavToFile(String site){
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    try{
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/test2.txt",true));
        writer.write("ROW1");
        writer.newLine();
        writer.write("ROW2");
        writer.newLine();
        writer.close();
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
```

Comment: I can't see the difference between this code and my code, did I post the code wrong? abit confused

Comment: I have just added "writer.newLine();" before closing it. I believe you want to add newline at the end of file.

Comment: I want the lines to be seperated in the file, it doesn't matter if I do newLine or not at this stage, it still appends to the same line

Comment: Then try using writer.write("\\r\\n"); where there is writer.newLine(); in above code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `writer.newLine();`

You should use `writer.write("\\n\\r");`

Comment: `newLine()` is the same as `write(System.getProperty("line.separator"))`, which *should* be the correct line termination for the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use `PrintWriter.println(String s)`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html

Comment: Still prints on the same row in my Android

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the final line break, append the `writer.newLine()` after `writer.write("Row2")`.
If there is no newLine being written, `writer.newLine()` may write the wrong line end marker into the file. Write it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you force it to write at the end of the file by including the `offset` in the write commands...

```
private void addToFavToFile(String site){
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    try{
        File fileToWrite = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/test2.txt");
        int endOfFile = (int)file.length();

        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileToWrite,true));

        String string1 = "ROW1";
        writer.write(File.separator + string1,endOfFile,string1.length);
        endOfFile += string1.length;

        String string2 = "ROW2";
        writer.write(File.separator + string2,endOfFile,string2.length);
        endOfFile += string2.length;

        writer.close();
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding one new line, try adding two newlines in a row.

One for going to the line below ROW1 and the other for inserting one more blank line.